# GPS library for Proteus

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

I am working on a project in which I have to connect my Arduino with a GPS module. In this project I need to get longitude, latitude, time and date from the GPS module and need to send these values via USB to a computer.

On this computer, I am going to design software in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, which will receive this data and display it on a map.

Now, before designing it in hardware, I want to simulate it on Proteus. I have searched in Proteus but there's no GPS module in it, so does anyone know any GPS module library for Proteus?

Comment: As far as I can tell, most GPS modules communicate over serial/UART. In this case, you should be able to add some sort of hardcoded serial string to be sent on the serial pins of the arduino, and as long as it is in the correct format, the GPS library should parse it as if it were from a real GPS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question so I thought to post it here so that others could also get benefit out of it. Here's the link to [GPS Library for Proteus - A complete step by step tutorial on How to download GPS Library for Proteus](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2015/12/gps-library-proteus.html).

From this link you can download the GPS Library which you need to add to the libraries folder of your Proteus software and you will have the GPS module in Proteus and you can design your simulation quite easily. More details are given in this link.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using the computer to interface, **you don't really need Arduino in the middle**.

You can hook the GPS module to the computer using a USB-UART bridge like one below:

[image: USB to serial]

The usual GPS modules (ebay or other hobby stores) output NMEA sentences over their serial port. Check the datasheet of your GPS module for the baud rate and the RX/TX pins. Connect the RX and TX lines of your GPS to the USB-serial module and you should be able to see NMEA output on a terminal emulator (set to right baud).

Once you see NMEA sentences over a terminal emulator, you can parse those in your application directly (bypassing terminal emulator) instead of using an Arduino.